# Android Maps v2 works only the first time is launched

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I followed all the steps for [sut up a Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) in my application for create a debug key.
The problem is that when I run the application in debug mode with eclipse for the first time everything works perfectly but later if I restart the application (not using eclipse but from my home) the map doesn't work anymore, it doesn't even appear... It only shows a gray page.

**MY MANIFEST**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
    android:debuggable="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_KEY" />
```

**MY CODE**

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                    if (googleMap != null) {
                        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom), 3000, null);
                        googleMap.clear();



                        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().title(values[0]).snippet(values[1]).position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));



                        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new Adapter_Marker(context));
                        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                                EDU.infosDialog(context, fieldNames, infos);

                            }
                        });
                        googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
```

**MY_LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/bar_messina" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

WHY ????

Comment: could you post your Logcat

Comment: You're restarting the same application or you export the apk file? I mean, the app still in debug mode? so, If you connected your device, can you see the logs?

Comment: I haven't export the .apk file... Eclipse save it on my phone and then when I unplug the USB connector the maps doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA-1 key is tie to the the software itself (eclipse in this case). If the project runs on a different pc software. I would suspect that the SHA-1 key is different. Change the SHA-1 key refer to your software see if it helps.

Comment: I haven't run it in a differente pc software I just runned it without using eclipse... Simply choosing it from the menu of the applications from my phone

Comment: Try clear the application's cache and data, in that way will start the app on your phone new. And see how it goes.

Comment: I don't know why but it created 2 application with the same name and the same package... I removed all the applications and it works perfectly